# Pymongo - Query all strings with certain date

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I have a mongo db ('test') with a collection ('main') that has a field with datetimes stored. An example date is as follows:

2017-07-20T22:56:28.121000Z

The dates are stored as a string.

I want to query the collection for all data occurring on 2017-07-20 and pull it into a pandas dataframe. Below is the code I am attempting:

```
import datetime
the_date = datetime.datetime(2017,7,20) # Date I want to query

import pymongo
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
collection = db.main

data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find({'time': { '$in':[the_date]}})))

data.head()
```

This just returns an empty frame. I am wondering how it is possible to query mongodb for all data with the specific date I am seeking. I see why the $in operator does not work, but don't have a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing real datetimes with strings.  MongoDB won't autoconvert the `$in` with a datetime to the `str()`equiv.   Try this; note the anchor:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find({'time': {'$regex': '^2017-07-20'}} )));
```

Comment: Great solution. I tried without the anchor and received an empty frame, so that tidbit was very important.